# Is there a quick way to export a Zotero reference to a .bib file without having to download a file?

Tags: copy-paste, text-editing, latex, cross-reference, zotero

The question is pretty self-explanatory but just to re-iterate:

Is there a quick way to export a Zotero reference to a .bib file without having to download a file?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to click a button that converts the reference to .bib format and adds it to the clipboard so that I can easily copy and paste it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set bibtex as a default output format in the Zotero preferences and then use [quick copy](https://www.zotero.org/support/creating_bibliographies#quick_copy) (i.e. drag&drop or a keyboard shortcut) to copy it to the clipboard.
This is only possible in the software (i.e. Standalone or Firefox add-on), not on the website.